# Decode BLE devices payload in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, zlib

I am receiving data from my BLE device using the [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble) package.

I have the following method :

```
_broadcastCharacteristSubscription = _flutterReactiveBle
          .subscribeToCharacteristic(_broadCastCharacteristic!)
          .listen((event) {
        Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList(event); 
        _handleBytesReceived(data);
      });
```

This data is byte stuffed and compressed into chunks.

I have done the byte stuffing to reconstitute the compressed content that looks like this :

```
I/flutter (13164): Current payload before decompression : xUO�� ��>�Ew�gL
```

Now i need to decompress this, so i have tried using `ZLibDecoder` because my client told me they use Zlib for compression :

[image]

So i have implemented the following :

```
  void _handleBytesReceived(Uint8List data) {
    String decoded = _decoder.convert(data);
    print("Ascii string compressed data : $decoded");
    if (currentPayload.isEmpty) {
      currentPayload = decoded;
      print("Current payload is now : $currentPayload");
    }
    else {
      for (var element in decoded.characters) {
        if (element != "~") {
          currentPayload += element;
        }
        else {
          currentPayload = currentPayload.replaceAll("~", "");
          print("Current payload before decompression : $currentPayload");
          currentPayload = _unzipPayload(currentPayload);
          print("Current payload after : $currentPayload");
          currentPayload = "";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  String _unzipPayload(String encoded) {
    return String.fromCharCodes(ZLibCodec(level: 6).decode(encoded.codeUnits));
  }
```

And i am getting the following error :

```
I/flutter (13164): Error from outside Flutter : FormatException: Filter error, bad data
  I/flutter (13164):  #0      _FilterImpl.processed (dart:io-patch/filter_patch.dart:13:71)
  I/flutter (13164): #1      _FilterSink.addSlice (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:505:29)
  I/flutter (13164): #2      _FilterSink.add (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:489:5)
  I/flutter (13164): #3      ZLibDecoder.convert (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:363:9)
  I/flutter (13164): #4      Codec.decode (dart:convert/codec.dart:30:34)
  I/flutter (13164): #5      ReactiveBleAPI._unzipPayload (package:myappname/api/reactive_ble_api.dart:213:53)
  I/flutter (13164): #6      ReactiveBleAPI._handleBytesReceived (package:myappname/api/reactive_ble_api.dart:203:28)
  I/flutter (13164): #7      ReactiveBleAPI._connectToDevice.<anonymous closure> (package:myappname/api/reactive_ble_api.dart:171:9)
  I/flutter (13164): #8      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
  I/flutter (13164): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
  I/flutter (13164): #10     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
  I/flutter (13164): #11     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:776:19)
  I/flutter (13164): #12     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:650:7)
  I/flutter (13164): #13     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
  I/flutter (13164): #14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
  I/flutter (13164): #15     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
  I/flutter (13164): #16     _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
  I/flutter (13164): #17     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
  I/flutter (13164): #18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
  I/flutter (13164): #19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

The decompression seems to failed, and i am pretty sure that the data is not corrupted unless i have got it wrong with my above conversions.

Am i doing something wrong with the `currentPayload.codeUnits` for example ? or in any part of it ?

**EDIT** : Here is the new code without trying to decode the initial bytes from the BLE (removing `String decoded = _decoder.convert(data)` as suggested in the comments :

```
void _resetPayload() {
    print("Current payload before compression : $currentPayload");
    List<int> finalList = [];
    for (var element in currentPayload) {
      if (element != 126) {
        finalList.add(element);
      }
    }
    String output = _unzipPayload(Uint8List.fromList(finalList));
    print("Current payload after compression : $output");
    currentPayload = Uint8List(0);
  }

  void _handleBytesReceived(Uint8List data) {
    print("Raw data : $data");
    //String decoded = _decoder.convert(data);
    // print("Decoded ascii data : $decoded");
    if (currentPayload.isEmpty) {
      currentPayload = data;
    }
    print("Current payload is : $currentPayload");
    for (var element in data.toList()) {
      if (currentPayload.contains(126)) {
        if (element == 126) {
          _resetPayload();
        }
        else {
          currentPayload.add(element);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  String _unzipPayload(Uint8List encoded) {
    try {
      List<int> decoded = _codec.decode(encoded);
      print("Decoded : $decoded");
      String result =  String.fromCharCodes(decoded);
      print("Result : $result");
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error unzipping $error");
    }
    return "";
  }
```

And here are the logs i am getting with the above code for example :

```
I/flutter (25368): Raw data : [126, 120, 1, 85, 79, 209, 10, 131, 48, 12, 252, 151, 60, 23, 113, 67, 157, 245, 103, 36]
I/flutter (25368): Current payload is : [126, 120, 1, 85, 79, 209, 10, 131, 48, 12, 252, 151, 60, 23, 113, 67, 157, 245, 103, 36]
I/flutter (25368): Current payload before compression : [120, 1, 85, 79, 209, 10, 131, 48, 12, 252, 151, 60, 23, 113, 67, 157, 245, 103, 36]
I/flutter (25368): Decoded : []
I/flutter (25368): Result : 
I/flutter (25368): Current payload after compression : 
D/BluetoothGatt(25368): onConnectionUpdated() - Device=C4:DE:E2:90:A6:DE interval=36 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
I/flutter (25368): Raw data : [126, 120, 1, 85, 140, 65, 10, 133, 48, 16, 67, 239, 146, 117, 23, 174, 123, 21, 145, 207]
I/flutter (25368): Current payload is : [126, 120, 1, 85, 140, 65, 10, 133, 48, 16, 67, 239, 146, 117, 23, 174, 123, 21, 145, 207]
I/flutter (25368): Current payload before compression : [120, 1, 85, 140, 65, 10, 133, 48, 16, 67, 239, 146, 117, 23, 174, 123, 21, 145, 207]
I/flutter (25368): Decoded : []
I/flutter (25368): Result : 
I/flutter (25368): Current payload after compression :
```

FINAL EDIT / ANSWER : Payload was empty because i was not requesting a higher MTU, not enough bytes were transferred. I have set it to 180 according to my BLE device.

Comment: You seem to be treating a stream of bytes as if they were characters. This is not a String (that's why you're seeing �; that's the decoder telling you it's not valid UTF-8). You need to  operate on the Uint8List directly. You should not call `String decoded = _decoder.convert(data)`

Comment: By the way, you don't need the `level: 6` in the `ZLibCodec`. The decoder doesn't care what level it was compressed with.

Comment: Oh thanks for your replies, so i should simply check the equivalent of "~" as the byte it's represented with inside the Uint8List (to do the byte stuffing) and uncompress the bytes directly ? I will try what you said and deal with `Uint8List` directly

Comment: Alright it's working ! i have no more errors but the decompressed `String` is empty, is that normal ? I am updating the question with the new logs

Comment: Do you know for certain that the compressed data is a legal UTF-8 encoded String? What stuffing algorithm are you using? This seems to assume that the value 126 can never appear in the compressed data, which is a very bad assumption (compressed bytes are random over the whole range).

Comment: It's working fine now ! i had to request the correct MTU (i don't know what that is) but my client told me that there were missing bytes that's all. with A MTU of 180 it's working, thanks for your help guys

Comment: @RobNapier feel free to answer with your very first comment, that was the solution to my question for others that might see this.

Comment: The MTU is the Maximum Transmission Unit. It's the largest amount of data that can be sent as a single packet across a particular connection. The default in BLE is generally 23 bytes. This device allows (and requires) larger packets so it doesn't have to chunk the data. This likely means it's using DLE (Data Length Extension). This should be fine on almost all modern hardware, but if you ever encounter an older phone (for example, an iPhone 6), it may not be interoperable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be treating a stream of bytes as if they were characters. This is not a String (that's why you're seeing �; that's the decoder telling you it's not valid UTF-8). You need to operate on the Uint8List directly. You should not call `String decoded = _decoder.convert(data)` .